# Click on history item shows unable to connect in hadoop 2.7.2

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

When I click on the `History` item in Hadoop Interface, it shows `Unable to connect` page.

[image: history]

[image: unable to connect]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To View the JobHistory User Interface, start the `jobhistoryserver` daemon. This daemon process is specific to MapReduce jobs and is not bundled with `start-all.sh`. This process has to be started separately.

**To Start:**

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```

**To Stop:**

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh stop historyserver
```

Add the `JobHistoryServer` properties in `mapred-site.xml`:

```
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
   <value>hostname_on_which_jobhistory_service_is_started:10020</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
   <value>hostname_on_which_jobhistory_service_is_started:19888</value>
</property>
```

***Note:*** If using, `Tez` or `Spark` the respective HistoryServer must be started to view the Job History.

Comment: I started before and I can see master:19888.jobhistory is running ,but hadoop doesnt show history on that page that I have mentioned.

Comment: In which node was it started? The URL is pointing to `slave2` node, replace the name with ip in the URL and try to connect.

Comment: I started just on master.

Comment: it means that I can only see the jobhistory on master?

Comment: Jobhistory has to be started on only one node on the cluster, it can be any node. If started on master node, it is sufficient. It can be accessed from all nodes. But make sure the properties as added in all nodes, check updated answer.